# dispersion_plot not working inspite of installing matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

i have installed `matplotlib` using pip in ubuntu 14.04 LTS.. but on running `dispersion_plot` this is showing the following error ..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/text.py", line 455, in dispersion_plot
from nltk.draw import dispersion_plot
ImportError: cannot import name dispersion_plot
```

I am new to python... can anyone suggest if there is a better way of installing `matplotlib` in `nltk`.

Comment: Can you go into a python console and type `>>> import pylab`?

Comment: So you are "self-learning"! Answer your own question to help others in the future, and maybe you get a badge like this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The examples of the online book are not quite right.

You may try this:

```
from nltk.draw.dispersion import dispersion_plot

words = ['Elinor', 'Marianne', 'Edward', 'Willoughby']
dispersion_plot(gutenberg.words('austen-sense.txt'), words)
```

You may also call it from a text directly:

```
from nltk.book import text1
from nltk.draw.dispersion import dispersion_plot

dispersion_plot(text1, ['monstrous'])
```

this way you import the function directly instead of calling the funcion from text object.
I realized this watching at the source code directly.

Hope this work for you

Comment: Just for others that may see this question: it's not just the examples in the book, but the method itself. NLTK `Text` objects have a method dispersion_plot that fails when you run it.

Comment: This seems to happen when `tkinter` is not installed and `nltk.draw.__init__.py` does not import `nltk.draw.dispersion.dispersion_plot` into the `nltk.draw` namespace.  There's an issue for this: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1339

Answer (score 0):

After importing it using spyder, this is how the plot would look.
[image: from nltk.draw.dispersion import dispersion_plot]